# Extract data from API object in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk

I am using an NLTK API to get the information by passing some text.

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/",data={'text':'I am a good boy'})
print(r.text)
```

The following is the Output.

```
{"probability": {"neg": 0.50955199890675162, "neutral": 0.6850996054094568, "pos": 0.49044800109324838}, "label": "neutral"}
```

How do i extract only "neutral" from this????Please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `r.json()` then access by key, .text will just give you a json string :

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/",data={'text':'I am a good boy'})
jsn_dict = r.json()
```

Then:

```
jsn_dict["probability"]["neutral"]
```

If we run the code, you will see we get what we need:

```
In [13]: import requests

In [14]: r = requests.post("http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/",data={'text':'I am a good boy'})

In [15]: jsn_dict = r.json()

In [16]: jsn_dict["probability"]["neutral"]
Out[16]: 0.14191475627838368
```